# QuickOSM / QGIS exported polygon not matching OSM

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, quickosm

I used QuickOSM / QGIS to grab some place data but the polygon / coordinates are not matching the original on OSM (nominatim). This is "Olive Garden" in Schaumburg IL. On OSM is is the below left image. After downloading / exporting using QuickOSM / QGIS it is the right image. I've not changed any setting. CRS is default 4326 W84.

On OSM the polygon is starting as: `[-88.0332509,42.0502153]...`
The exported QuickOSM / QGIS one is starting as: `[-88.0332143, 42.050252]...`

How to export this to match the original coordinate at OSM?

[image]

Comment: I just tried the query "name=Olive Garden" IN "Schaumburg IL". It works well for me, EPSG 4326. Which OSM source background are you using? My first coordinate is `[ -88.0332143, 42.050252 ]` which is the same as in OSM https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/1483640394#map=19/42.05015/-88.03304

Comment: Source background as in the URL? It's https://overpass.openstreetmap.fr/api/  Did your polygon match? I'm matching it using http://geojsonlint.com

Comment: That's why I was asking your background URL? Why wouldn't it be a problem with Mapbox background? Or geojsonlint.com ? I downloaded the polygon with QuickOSM, which gives me `[ -88.0332143, 42.050252 ]` which is the same as https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/1483640394#map=19/42.05015/-88.03304 in QGIS, the OSM background matchs perfectly with QuickOSM result. Have you tried in QGIS and checking coordinates from QGIS?

Comment: Ok I found the issue, it is not QGIS. The polygon on OSM is incorrect itself because it's not correctly laying on the underlining place exactly. Can't notice it on OSM because there is no building boundary on their map but when checked on other sites which have the building boundary I see the polygon is off. But thanks for your help.

Comment: It's possible to have building boundary on OSM.org. You need an account and then you can turn on/off imagery (building boundary), it has many providers available. Depending on the background provider, the building is fine in OSM. Keep in mind that's a rare to have single imagery provider with 100% correctness. So it's sometimes needed to do an average between different providers.